# Letter spacing and line-height not only affecting text elements

Tags: css

I defined main stylesheet (default CSS of my project) like this:

```
body {
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 0.75em; /* 12px */
    line-height: 1.5; /* font-size:1(12px) + line-space:0.33(4px) = 16px */
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
}
```

`letter-spacing` and `line-height` works perfectly.
but, I found that two of them affect ul-li elements too.
I want that they affect text only not ul-li or any other elements.

Is there any side-effect on letter-spacing and line-height which I don't know?
If so, how could I make line-height and letter-spacing affect text only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the body definition you apply your style to all elements in your page. Try to identify the desired text elements like div, a, span, etc. and make a new css entry like this:

```
body {
    color: #000000;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 0.75em; /* 12px */
}
div, a, span {
    line-height:1.5; /* font-size:1(12px) + line-space:0.33(4px) = 16px */
    letter-spacing:0.03em;
}
```

or apply a seperate style with specific key to your text elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the CSS for the `<p>` tag only, and put all texts in a `p` element:

```
p {
    line-height:1.5;
}
```

Comment: this is probably a better idea than setting it globally with `body` and then unsetting it for specific elements: just set it for the elements or page sections where you actually want to use it.

Comment: For this to work you must not put your UL inside a P element. The HTML spec does not allow UL elements inside P elements.

Answer (score 2):

> but, I found that two of them affect ul-li elements too.

So just make another selector for ul/li elements that sets it back to normal.

```
ul, li {
    letter-spacing:0em;
    line-height:1;
}
```

Comment: @inti - indeed, should have been `0em`, not `1em`. My bad; typing in too much of a hurry. Fixed. Thanks.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just reset your ul li elements back to the default line-height after the body style?

```
body {
  color: #000000;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 0.75em; /* 12px */
  line-height:1.5; /* font-size:1(12px) + line-space:0.33(4px) = 16px */
  letter-spacing:0.03em;
}

ul, ul li {
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `line-height` and `letter-spacing` back to `normal` on `li` elements:

```
li {
    letter-spacing: normal;
    line-height: normal;     /* this is actually 0em */
}
```